# Как сделать поиск по DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть DataGrid связанный с БД, в нем есть столбцы в которых хранятся разные данные (например есть столбец "Название фирмы"). Так же есть TextBox в котором вводится например что-то из столбца "Название фирмы" и в DataGrid происходит отображение этого (или просто можно выделить цветом). Своего рода поиск, но как это реализовать не знаю.
Подключение к БД делаю вот так C#:

```
Project_Administrator.ProjectAdministratorDataSet projectAdministratorDataSet = ((Project_Administrator.ProjectAdministratorDataSet)(this.FindResource("projectAdministratorDataSet")));
Project_Administrator.ProjectAdministratorDataSetTableAdapters.СustomerTableAdapter projectAdministratorDataSetСustomerTableAdapter = new Project_Administrator.ProjectAdministratorDataSetTableAdapters.СustomerTableAdapter();
projectAdministratorDataSetСustomerTableAdapter.Fill(projectAdministratorDataSet.Сustomer);
System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource сustomerViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("сustomerViewSource")));
сustomerViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();
```

А в XAML так выглядит:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="сustomerDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" LayoutUpdated="DataGrid_LayoutUpdated">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="idCustomerColumn" Binding="{Binding IdCustomer}" Header="Id Заказчика" Width="Auto" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="nameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Название организации" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="locationColumn" Binding="{Binding Location}" Header="Местоположение" Width="Auto" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="addressColumn" Binding="{Binding Address}" Header="Адрес" Width="Auto" CanUserSort="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="phoneColumn" Binding="{Binding Phone}" Header="Телефон" Width="Auto" CanUserSort="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="emailColumn" Binding="{Binding Email}" Header="Эл. почта" Width="Auto" CanUserSort="False"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="representativeColumn" Binding="{Binding Representative}" Header="Представитель" Width="Auto" CanUserSort="False"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Работайте с источником строк для таблицы.

Comment: Вы предлагаете искать в самой бд, а не в датагриде, увы я не знаю как это сделать на данный момент, я только изучаю wpf, а поиск уже требуется реализовать

Comment: Нет, не в самой БД.В модели или во вью модели. Обратите внимание на объект, который является `ItemsSource` для вашей таблицы

Answer (score 1):

что-то типа такого можно сделать...

```
TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
string filter = t.Text;
ICollectionView viewSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(сustomerDataGrid.ItemsSource);
if (filter == "") viewSource.Filter = null;
else
{
    viewSource.Filter = o =>
    {
     КЛАСС p = o as КЛАСС;
     return p.СВОЙСТВО.ToString().Contains(filter);
    };
    сustomerDataGrid.ItemsSource = viewSource;
 }
```