# Фильтрация ListView по выбранному элементу в ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть:

StudentsList (ObservableCollection); GroupsList - ObservableCollection.

ComboBox(выбор группы); ListView(выбор студента)

Выбрав группу, в ListView необходимо оставить только студентов конкретной группы.

Стоит ли в MainViewModel заводить еще одну ObservableCollection, которая будет состоять из конкретных элементов StudentList? (однако, почему-то ListView не обновляется) Или имеются более рациональные способы?

Так же в ComboBox, по-мимо элементов класса Group, необходимо первым полем поставить поле "Все группы", каким образом это сделать?? На данный момент ComboBox выглядит так (смотреть не обязательно):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="20,0,20,20" SelectedIndex="0">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupNum}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

ListView

```
<ListView Name="StudentsView"  ItemsSource="{Binding StudentsList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0,0,0">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Padding="10">
                    <Border.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
                                      Command="{Binding DataContext.AddStudent,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                              AncestorType=Window}}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </Border.InputBindings>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GetGroupNum}" Margin="10,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

SelectedGroup

```
public Group SelectedGroup
{
    get { return selectedGroup; }
    set
    {
        selectedGroup = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedGroup");
        FullListStudents = StudentsList;
        StudentsList = new ObservableCollection<Student>(FullListStudents.Where( (x) => x.CurrentGroup == selectedGroup));
        SelectedStudent = StudentsList.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Писать конкретные реализации не прошу, просто подсказать идейно.

Comment: То есть, у вас должны быть в ListBox’е либо все студенты, либо конкретная группа?

Comment: `Стоит ли в MainViewModel заводить еще одну ObservableCollection, которая будет состоять из конкретных элементов StudentList?` - как вариант, только надо `OnPropertyChanged` не забыть для нее вызвать чтобы UI узнал что пора обновляться

Comment: Да, в ListView должны быть или все студенты, или конкретная группа выбранная в комбобоксе. Я завел отдельное поле, и изменил обработчик SelectedGroup, однако ListView не обновляется.

Comment: Так как вы не искали готовую реализацию, то написал ответ по большей части состоящей из ссылок. При необходимости могу дополнить примером. Если в ходе возникнут вопросы - не стесняйтесь спрашивать. Возможно вам будет удобнее обсудить в чат режиме, всегда можете пинговать в [F# комнате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) .

Comment: Я не против примера, даже наоборот. По поводу первого: я так полагаю, что тогда мое поле SelectedGroup при использовании CollectionViewSource становится не актуальным, что для меня не очень хорошо. 
Касательно второго: там аналогичная ситуация, хотелось бы обойтись без CollectionViewSource, ибо при его использовании в SelectedStudent так же отпадает надобность, хотя я возможно в чем-то ошибаюсь, но в целом второй вариант выглядит для меня пока достаточно сложным.

Comment: `MouseBinding` из `StackPanel` уберите, он там не нужен, он переехал в `Border`. В предыдущем вопросе я немного не понятно, наверное, написал.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы добавить дополнительный элемент в `ComboBox` можно воспользоваться `CompositeCollection`. Такой вопрос уже задавался несколько раз, с подробностями можно ознакомиться по следующим ссылкам

- [ComboBox с элементом "Не выбрано"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633058/combobox-%D1%81-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE/633061)
- [Первый элемент ComboBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674253/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-combobox/674317)
- [Как отобразить в ComboBox элемент, которого нет в списке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658777/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-combobox-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B5/658789)

Чтобы установить фильтр используйте `ICollectionView`, подробнее можно прочесть в самых разных источниках - от книг до вопросов на SO, ниже перечислены несколько источников, которые будут полезны

- [Как сделать поиск по DataGrid](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527420/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-datagrid)
- [How to: Filter Data in a View](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-filter-data-in-a-view)
- [Implementing a ListView Filter with Josh Smith's WPF MVVM Demo App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188623/implementing-a-listview-filter-with-josh-smiths-wpf-mvvm-demo-app)

Answer (score 2):

У вас по идее классический случай master/detail view.

Возможно, вам имеет смысл протащить существование псевдогруппы, содержащей всех студентов, на уровень бизнес-логики. Получится просто. (Я заменил класс `Student` на `string`, и убрал для простоты `ObservableCollection<>`.)

```
class Group
{
    public Group(IEnumerable<string> students, string name)
    {
        Students = students;
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Students { get; }
}

class MainVM
{
    public MainVM()
    {
        Groups = new[]
        {
            new Group(new[] { "Fritz", "Uwe", "Jan" }, "Norddeutschland"),
            new Group(new[] { "Johannes", "Christian", "Andreas" }, "Süddeutschland")
        };
        var allStudents = Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Students).ToList();
        var totalGroup = new Group(allStudents, "(all)");
        GroupsAndTotal = new[] { totalGroup }.Concat(Groups);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Group> Groups { get; }
    public IEnumerable<Group> GroupsAndTotal { get; }
    public IEnumerable<string> AllStudents { get; }
}
```

Ну и разметка:

```
<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsAndTotal}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding GroupsAndTotal/Students}"/>
```

Результат:

[image: вот такой вот получился]

Comment: Да, я понял о чем Вы, спасибо. Однако у меня у группы нету списка студентов, из-за разногласий отказался от данной идеи.

Выбрав вариант из первой ссылки(предложенной Foggy Finder)
Пытаюсь сделать что-то похожее: 
Оставить FullListStudents - все студенты.
StudentsList - студенты которые будут уходить на ListView.

В ComboBox, выбрав группу, при установке св-ва SelectedGroup 
с помощью Linq выбираю студентов с нужной группой. 

Проблемы 2:
1. Почему-то не работает DisplayMemberPath как у вас.
2. Не понятно как связать пункт "Any Group" c SelectedGroup.

Comment: @TorSen: А _почему_ у группы нет списка студентов? А где ж ему ещё быть? Если у вас есть сущность «группа», то можно хотя бы сделать вычисляемое свойство `IEnumerable<Student> Students => AllStudents.Where(st => st.Group == this);`.

Comment: @TorSen: Если вы пошли по пути фильтрации, так можно тоже.

Comment: @TorSen: Возможно, `DisplayMemberPath` не работает, потому что вы пытаетесь привязаться к полю, а не свойству?

Comment: Изначально у группы была коллекция студентов, но позже от этой идеи я отказался. (видимо зря). Св-во то можно добавить, однако у меня по двойному щелчку на элемент ListView открывается окно с редактированием, потому вариант с IEnumerable, наверное не подойдет, хотя я могу ошибаться.

Привязываю к св-ву.

Answer (score 0):

Итого:

```
        <ComboBox Margin="20,0,20,20" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGroup}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding GroupNum}" SelectedIndex="-1">
            <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <ComboBoxItem TabIndex="0" Content="Any Group" Selector.Selected="ComboBox_Selected"/>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ComboBoxCollection}}"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        </ComboBox>

    public Group SelectedGroup
    {
        get { return selectedGroup; }
        set
        {
            selectedGroup = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedGroup");
            StudentsList.Clear();
            if (value == null)
            {
                StudentsList = new ObservableCollection<Student>(FullListStudents);
            }
            else StudentsList = new ObservableCollection<Student>(FullListStudents.Where(x => x.CurrentGroup == selectedGroup));
            OnPropertyChanged("StudentsList");
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedStudent");
        }
    }

    private void ComboBox_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MainViewModel)this.DataContext).SelectedGroup = null;
    }
```

Имеющиеся проблемы:

1. Некорректно отображающийся номер группы.
2. Подсветка пункта "Any Group" в красный цвет.
3. Нарушение паттерна MVVM.
4. Сомнительная (на мой взгляд) реализация св-ва SelectedGroup.

   Работает конечно, в крайнем случае, придется перегрузить у группы метод ToString и оставить как есть.